# Cakephp looping through database saves, for some reason it only saves on the last instance of loop?

Tags: database, cakephp, loops

I'm trying to get this loop to save a new record to the database in cakephp on each iteration but for some reason its only saving it on the last one (so in this case it saves a record called "test9" but no others.. this type of save has worked for me so far in cakephp and I am completely stumped by this, I would appreciate any advice

The debug output just gives this for each record (including the save that works), so I can't determine anything from it:

26  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `proxylinks` AS `Proxylink` WHERE `Proxylink`.`id` = 13         1   1   0
27  SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `proxylinks` AS `Proxylink` WHERE `Proxylink`.`id` = 13         1   1   0
28  UPDATE `proxylinks` SET `link` = 'test9' WHERE `proxylinks`.`id` = 13       1       0

```
  $count = 10;
    $v = 1;
      do {

          ######### save link to database
          $this->Prox->Proxylink->set(array('link' => 'test' . $v));
          $this->Prox->Proxylink->save();

          $v++;
      } while ($v < $count);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [call `->create()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data), otherwise it's updating the previously saved record.

Quoting the manual:

> When calling `save` in a loop, don't forget to call `create()`.

Comment: thanks.. yeah I just saw that actually, sorry for asking a dumb question :).. its just I could've sworn it worked fine before for me where it would create a new row without me calling this so I guess I never realized this was necessary